# How to use Azure Logic App to upload a file with PUT and save to Sharepoint?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an app that looks like this:

[image]

It was working 2 weeks ago but I couldn't figure out how to get the filename from the multipart PUT.  I can see it in the headers...  QUESTION 1: how do get the filename as a property to the file save block?

QUESTION 2 I came back to it today and now it is failing with: "This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.Form, Files, InputStream, or BinaryRead has been invoked"  what does this mean?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "logic-apis-eastus.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "46a9418a-454b-4114-ba00-0e7a4bcfd9d9",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.Form, Files, InputStream, or BinaryRead has been invoked.\r\nclientRequestId: 46a9418a-454b-4114-ba00-0e7a4bcfd9d9\r\nserviceRequestId: 46a9418a-454b-4114-ba00-0e7a4bcfd9d9"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help on these questions or even a more exact example would help.  All I could find is similar but different in some way to what I want to do.

This is the Create File input (with the content truncated for brevity):

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=6a99a67e31cf4de3a14e2c23917b4874",
  "$content": " . . .",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"test2.zip\"",
        "Content-Type": "application/zip"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/zip",
        "$content": ". . ."
 }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I’m confused, where is the file name coming from that you want to use? Is it in the HTTP trigger? I can’t see it in your question.

Comment: Thanks you can see it in the multipart headers above.  I was stuck how to get it out to use in the file save which it looks like the answer below answered.

Comment: So you’re good then?

Answer (score 1):

To get file name from a request header you can use expressions.

- Created logic app as shown below,
  [image]
- In file name, used expression **triggerOutputs()['queries']['filename']** to pass file name from headers of http request trigger,
  [image]
- Once run logic app, able to get file name from headers.
  Output of http request:
  [image]

Input of create file:
[image]

For question2, set method type in http request as put.
[image]

Also try to change content type of request body to application/json and check if it works.

Reference MS [document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  It actually ended up slightly different function properties but your answer provided the missing clue to get my logic app working.